# Comparing and printing elements inside bootstrap panels

Tags: javascript, arrays, twitter-bootstrap, element

I'm working on a project where I'm gathering data from an API for a school's timetable. This is what I've coded to get all the necessary data I need;

```
var timetable = [];
var days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 
'Friday', 'Saturday'];



// Go through the data and pick specific information
for (var i = 0; i < json.reservations.length; i++) {
    if (json.reservations[i].resources != null) {
        for (var j = 0; j < json.reservations[i].resources.length; j++) {


            var reservation = json.reservations[i];
            var resource = json.reservations[i].resources[j];

            // Get student group
            if (resource.type === "student_group") {
                if (timetable.indexOf("name")) {
                    var studentGroup = timetable.push(resource.name.bold() + "<br/>");
                }
            }

            // Get scheduling group
            if (resource.type === "scheduling_group") {
                if (timetable.indexOf("name")) {
                    var schedulingGroup = timetable.push(resource.name + "<br/>")
                }
            }


           // Get rooms
           if (resource.type === "room") {
               if (timetable.indexOf("code")) {
                   var room = timetable.push(resource.code.bold() + "<br/>" + "<br/>");
               }                                     
           }
       }                              
   }

   // Get subject
   if (reservation != null) {
       if (timetable.indexOf("subject")) {
           var subject = timetable.push("<br/>" + reservation.subject.bold() + "<br/>");
       }
   }

   // Day name (Mon, Tue, Wed...)
   var day = new Date(reservation.startDate);                          
   var date = timetable.push(days[day.getDay()].bold() + "<br/>");

   // Starting timestamp
   if (reservation != null) { 
       var start = reservation.startDate;
       var startStr = start.split("-").join('/').slice(0, 10) + "<br/>" + start.slice(11, 16);
       lukkari.push(startStr + " - ");
   }

   // Ending timestamp
   if (reservation != null) {
       var end = reservation.endDate;
       var endStr = end.slice(11, 16);
       timetable.push(endStr + "<br/> <br/>");
   }

   var line = timetable.push("_______________________________<br/>");

  // Print
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = timetable.join("");
```

Here is the output from printing the data into the `timetable` array;

```
A440.2   

KL25AB10403-3001

Monday
2017/01/16
10:00 - 13:00

_______________________________


A440.4

KL04DVTT04-3002

Monday
2017/01/16
13:15 - 16:00

_______________________________


A320.2

KC00AKO10-3007

Tuesday
2017/01/17
09:00 - 11:45

_______________________________


A420.4    

KC00AMT1010-3010

Tuesday
2017/01/17
12:15 - 14:00

_______________________________


A420.4

KC00AMT1010-3010

Wednesday
2017/01/18
08:00 - 10:45

_______________________________


A350.3

KL04BTTIVE1-3001

Wednesday
2017/01/18
11:00 - 13:00

_______________________________


A440.4

KL04DVTT04-3002

Wednesday
2017/01/18
13:15 - 15:00

_______________________________


A440.2

KL25AB10403-3001

Thursday
2017/01/19
08:00 - 09:45

_______________________________


A320.2

KC00AKO10-3007

Thursday
2017/01/19
10:00 - 11:45
```

But I don't want this information just inside an array. I was thinking about printing the data from each day (Monday, Tuesday, etc...) into their own columns.

Here I was thinking of using collapsing bootstrap panels and each panel has their own respective day name eg. Monday, Tuesday...

Is there any quick and effective solution to link the day name from the data I gathered (as you can see from the `timetable` array) to a panel with the same day name?

...Or do you have any alternative ideas for a smart solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for this I would use a templating engine like Handlebars.js

Recently I completed a project that made extensive use of Handlebars with Bootstrap 3, and I found it to be very easy to adapt for use on that project

It is too much effort to teach you Handlebars in this panel, but it will allow you to define an HTML template with {{tokens}} where your data will go, and it has useful features like iterating over a provided dataset to construct as many panels as necessary to display all data in the set

Syntax ends up looking like this in your markup:

```
{{#each event}}
  <div class="panel">
    <h3>{{event.dayOfWeek}}</h3>
    <p>
      <label>{{event.date}}</label>
      <label>{{event.startTime}} - {{event.endTime}}</label>
    </p>
  </div>
{{/each}}
```

Super easy to use.  Look it up.  Great tool.